# How can I only show one form field on the screen at a time in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a form that only shows one textFormField at a time.   I created a `Form` with a `key:` with a `Container()` as the child.    That `Container()` calls a method that returns a `TextFormField` Widget based on a counter that increments each time I click a next button.   Everything works except the text that I enter in the field stays in between each field change.  Here is my relevant code:

```
...              
 Form(
   key: _formkey,
     child: Column(
         children: <Widget>[
             SizedBox(
                height: _height * .10,
                ),
             if (pageCount > 0 && pageCount <= 2)
             _createField(pageCount),
             RaisedButton(onPressed: ()=> _next()),

...

void _next() {
    if (pageCount < 10) {
      setState(() {
        pageCount++;
      });
    }
  }

...

Widget _createField(int count) {
    switch (count) {
      case 1:
        return TextFormField(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
            hintText: 'name',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey[500],
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            ),
          ),
          validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'enter your display name' : null,
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() => displayName = val);
          },
        );
        break;
      case 2:
        return TextFormField(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
            hintText: 'email',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey[500],
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            ),
          ),
          validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'enter an email' : null,
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() => email = val);
          },
        );
        break;
 
...

      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
```

The hint text and validation works, the only problem is that whatever I type in stays there on the next field.  I tried using a `TextEditingController` to clear the field, but maybe I'm not using it right because it either didn't work or sometimes I got an error that the controller was called on null.   I'm not sure where I would put it in my case.  My ultimate goal is to preserve screen real estate while filling out the form.   I'm open to suggestions on other ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

@override
void dispose() {
  _controller.dispose(); // DO NOT FORGET TO DISPOSE THE CONTROLLER
  super.dispose();
}

void _next() {
if (pageCount < 10) {
  setState(() {
    if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
      // update the variable by saving the form
      _formkey.currentState.save();
      pageCount++;
    }
  });
}

Widget _createField(int count) {
    switch (count) {
      case 1:
        // set the text to the correct variable
        _controller.text = displayName ?? '';
        return Center(
          child: TextFormField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            decoration: InputDecoration().copyWith(
              hintText: 'name',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[500],
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              ),
            ),
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            controller: _controller,
            validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'enter your display name' : null,
            // update the variable as the user navigates through the form
            onSaved: (val) => displayName = val,
          ),
        );
        break;
      case 2:
        _controller.text = email ?? '';
        return TextFormField(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          decoration: InputDecoration().copyWith(
            hintText: 'email',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey[500],
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            ),
          ),
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          controller: _controller,
          validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'enter an email' : null,
          onSaved: (val) => email = val,
        );
        break;
...
          default:
            _controller.text = '';
            setState(() => pageCount = 1);
            return null;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Lee3, passing _controller to the method now clears the field.  But my validator isn't working right now.  I also just noticed that when I go back to previous fields, it keeps the validator error under the field.   Anything that can be done about that?

Comment: I have updated my answer to validate the current field in the `_next()` method before allowing the user to progress to the next field. I hope this helps.

Comment: Also, with your solution, going back to edit a field clears it as well

Comment: Your edit fixed validation.  I marked as answer. Thank you!   I guess I can live with clearing the field with going back.  Unless you think there is a way around that?

Comment: In your switch cases, set the `TextField`'s current value to that of the corresponding variable, if not null.

Comment: Check my edited answer for a complete working solution.

Comment: Thanks again, but I think my last request wasn't clear.   When the user goes back, I prefer that they see what they typed previously, but with this solution it clears the field.   If that's not possible, I can live with it though.   Not as important as everything else.

Comment: The update addresses that. Loading the current values from the variables into the `TextField`s as the user navigates through the form. Note that the values are updated in the `onSaved` callback as opposed to the `onUpdated` callback and the form is save in the `_saved()` method. This is necessary for the result you are after.

Comment: You may also wish to call the `_save()` function when the user navigates backwards to keep the UI experience as you had it.

Comment: Im so sorry.  You are absolutely right.  I missed the change you made with `formkey.currentState.save();` so naturally it wasn't working for me at first.   Fantastic.  Thanks so much again.   Great stuff.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Please double check that you marked the answer as correct.